# Move div postion without touch - only PHP

Tags: php, jquery

I have

```
<div id="above">  Ram is good boy.   </div>
<div id="below">  Sita is good girl. </div>
```

I just want to change this html structure using php or jquery as follow without touching

```
<div id="below">  Sita is good girl. </div>
<div id="above">  Ram is good boy.   </div>
```

Comment: PHP is a server-side language; it can't change client-side HTML. You'll need JavaScript for that.

Comment: You can change HTML using JS. What kind of change you want to make?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use jquery:

```
$("#below").after($("#above"));
```

the explanation: you have two divs - one with `id="below"`, one with `id="above"`.

first you set your reference to the div, that you want to hold in place:

```
$("#below")
```

then you have to tell jquery, what to do:

```
.after()
```

the jquery after function needs content to place behind the selected element (in your case #below). since you want the other element to be moved, you select this id.

$("#above")

put all together:

```
    $("#below").after($("#above"));
```

Comment: Need more support sir, sorry it is not working by me... here it is...
https://jsfiddle.net/97Lfqpr1/

Comment: you have not included jquery in your fiddle, that's why it's not working. https://jsfiddle.net/97Lfqpr1/1/ - here is the library included...

Comment: for your own page, you need to include jquery either via cdn: <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"> </script> or download it and include it from your local host: <script src="./path-to-jquery/jquery.min.js">

Comment: if it works, i'd appreciate if you accept the solution as a solution ;)